# Nginx rewrite rules arabic issue,

Tags: magento, nginx, url-rewriting, arabic

Hello could anyone help me with this rewrite issue please?

**encoded link :** http://example.com/view/%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%88-%D9%87%D9%88-%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B3-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%88%D9%87

**Decoded link :** http://example.com/view/شهر-مايو-هو-شهر-العرائس-في-محلات-وجوه

I did tried the encoded link in nginx and in magento without success.

Is there any way to get this working in nginx with those "%".

do not hesitates to ask for more information if needed.

Regards,

peacengell.

Comment: Hey, what the question is?

Comment: How to make this type redirect  links work in nginix.

Comment: Still not clear, what does not work?

Comment: Hello @AlexeyTen,
The question is simple how to make those two rewrite to work.
These two links are are the same things
One is encoded and other one is decoded link
The issue is nginx is not doing the rewrite 
anyone can help.

Comment: You still didn't show the rewrite

Comment: Hello @AlexeyTen Sorry here is the rewrite.

rewrite ^/view/%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%88-%D9%87%D9%88-%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B3-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%88%D9%87  http://example.com/aboutus permanent ; 
Please help me if you can thanks.

Comment: You should write it without url encoding.

Comment: Like this you mean into the rewrite.conf file  
rewrite ^/view/شهر-مايو-هو-شهر-العرائس-في-محلات-وجوه  http://www.example.com/aboutus permanent ;

Comment: Yes. But, anyway, why you want such a specific redirect?

Comment: Well it's for a website curently on dev and they has this url before and needed to be redirect to a new one, will nginx read these arbic languages? I will give it a try and get back to you thanks for your help.

Comment: Nginx has no idea about languages. It uses bytes. And it decodes url before matching

Comment: Hey @AlexeyTen that great it worked I never imagine that nginx will take this Arabic URL. That great. Thanks alot for your help. You save me a month that I was looking into this. Cheers mate. make a post so that I can vote it mate. Great.

Comment: Hey @AlexeyTen I'm having another issue with another one  "^/en/search?s(\=wow)$" does not match  " I get this in the rewritelog.    rewrite ^/en/search?s(\=wow)$ http://example.com$1? permanent ;
see if you could help me with this one thanks alot.

Comment: Query params are not part of URI. So rewrite don't know them

Comment: So there is no way to make this work?

Comment: There is, but it would be better to describe real problem and do it in another post

Comment: Hello @AlexeyTen Got a way of doing it .

---
location /en/search {
        if ($args ~ "s=wow") {
rewrite ^ $scheme://$host permanent;
__

the things is whe use http it work and goes to http.
but when use https it rdirect to http not https do you have any idea?

thanks If needed I will create another post.

THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP